# Fetching URL without clicking on Chrome Plugin

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i am successful in fetching the current tab url in chrome plugin and i am also able to store it in mysql db using crossdomain ajax. but these all happen only when i click on the plugin is it possible to automate it as soon as tab is changed ?

```
window.addEventListener("load", windowLoaded, false);
```

i want to initiate the windowloaded function as soon as the tab is changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the chrome.tabs Events google offers. In your case the most appropriate seems the [onActiveChanged-Event](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#event-onActiveChanged).

But remember to [set the permission](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#permissions) in your manifest-file. Otherwise it won't work.

Also note that this [won't work in content scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html).

Answer (score 1):

found this very useful but when i try it out

```
chrome.tabs.onActiveChanged.addListener(function(tabId,selectInfo){
 alert("fooooooo");
});
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addListener' of undefined

Any solution for this ?

Comment: weird... have you tried another event? i am using onUpdated and it works fine. maybe you call this script in a content_script?